# Update Web API "Individual Accounts" sample to use ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oauth, membership

I've started with the code provided with the Web API "Individual Accounts" sample here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

We'd like to swap out the oauth provider and use older ASP.NET Membership Provider instead of newer ASP.NET Identity one.

1) Is that possible? Do we just provide a new implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider?

2) Has anyone already done it?

Thanks

Comment: What's your reason for using Membership?

Comment: We have existing web apps that use Membership.